# IntelliJ Idea не видит переменную, созданную только что

Tags: java, intellij-idea, переменные

Недавно после установки Intellij Idea 2016.3.2 появилась проблема при создании объектов классов. В данном случае в третьей строке пишет, что переменная 'c' не создана, и выбрасывает ошибку, а во второй строке - что переменная 'c' никогда не используется. Пересохранение/перезапуск не помогает, в дебаг-режиме этой переменной как будто не существует. Остальные классы работают нормально

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Circle с = new Circle(-2,3,5);
   System.out.println(c.isInCircle(0,2));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Никаких ошибок больше нет? Если навести на красную `c` внутри скобок, что будет написано? `Cannot resolve symbol` ?

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Comment: Я бы не стал закрывать как вызванный опечаткой, потому что проблема достаточно частая. Я даже не проверяя код догадался по скриншоту :)

Answer (score 6):

Предположу, что одна из `с` русская, а вторая латинская.

Comment: помогло, спасибо!

Comment: @Diana, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него :)